# Overriding/Adding to Django URLs in settings rather than urls

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

It seems that the latest Django debug toolbar module has changed to middleware now and requires explicit URL setup to work. With my Django projects I always try to keep settings organised based on environment and not have `if settings.DEBUG` littered all over the settings files and project.

***My settings layout is a general:***

```
common.py (everything in here)
development.py (dev only things here)
production.py (prod only things here)
```

Is there a way in Django 1.10 I can add to the URLs in the development.py file so that I can keep away from `if settings.DEBUG`. Or will we be forced to use this method if wanting to use the new version of the debug toolbar?

***I just find the below a bit of an anti-pattern***

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not feel like testing for the value of `settings.DEBUG` in your URL configuration, you may manage your URLs with a pattern similar to the one you are using for your settings.

Instead of a `urls.py` file, you would have a `urls` package with this structure:

```
urls
├── __init__.py
├── common.py
├── local.py
└── production.py
```

In your different settings files you would specify which URL conf file to use this way:

```
# settings/local.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls.local'
```

```
# settings/production.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls.production'
```

The `urls/common.py` file will expose a `urlpattern` member containing all the URL patterns common to all configurations which you will import and use in `urls/local.py` and `urls/production.py`.

For example:

```
# urls/common.py
urlpatterns = [
    # Put all common URL patterns here
]
```

```
# urls/local.py
from .common import urlpatterns as common_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = common_urlpatterns + [
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

If you want my opinion, this solution feels like overkill given that, as opposed to settings, URL configurations should not differ much between environments.

Comment: Strangely enough, I did not think of this at first even though I am doing it for settings. DOH!
But your method does seem like a reasonable option. Thank you

Comment: This is a decent solution, thanks! One caveat about the module name. I'm using python 3.6 with Django 1.11 and it turns out it requires the absolute module path instead of relative `ROOT_URLCONF = '{{ project_name }}.urls'` so one would need to have `project_name` in the setting files, e.g. 'xxx.urls.local'